# Conversion of the varchar value '781015020002' overflowed an int column

Tags: sql-server

```
 UPDATE CaTbItemRequest 
     SET vcReqStatus='complete' ,
         vcItemCode='781015020002'
     WHERE inItemRequestNo=2000003 
     and vcDelFlag='false' and vcItemNatureType='Services'
```

vcItemCode = varchar(50)

The error MSG is

> Msg 248, Level 16, State 1, Procedure ExtendCode, Line 12
>   The conversion of the varchar value '781015020002' overflowed an int column.
>   The statement has been terminated.

Comment: Are there any triggers on the table ?

Comment: is this an issue of datatypes? int column won't store such a large number

Comment: If `vcItemCode` is a `varchar(50)` then the error you have would be impossible on it's own (see the Edit in my answer). I agree with @SQLApostle, I suggest we have a trigger, or something. Please post the full DDL of your table, importantly, **include** the DDL of any triggers, constraint, etc. on the table. If there are triggers, and they are inserting into another table, **include** the DDL of those tables as well. The query you have above will not generate the error you are experience, if the column `vcItemCode` is really a `varchar(50)`.

Answer (score 2):

The error is rather obvious here; the problem is your value `'781015020002'`, which has a value greater than 2^31-1, and, as a very safe guess, your column `vcItemCode` is the datatype `int`. You can't store a value greater than 2^31-1 in a column of the datatype `int`.

You either need to use a lower value, or change the datatype of your column `vcItemCode` to `bigint`.

*Edit: OP has updated their post to suggest that the datatype of the column `vcItemCode` is a `varchar(50)`. If, therefore, the query was as simple as the OP makes out, then this error would not occur. As a very simple example:*

```
USE Sandbox;
GO
CREATE TABLE test (vcItemCode varchar(50));
GO
INSERT INTO test
VALUES ('1');
GO

UPDATE test
SET vcItemCode = '781015020002';
GO

DROP TABLE test;
```

*Note that no error occurs, as the value `'781015020002'` has no reason to be implicitly converted to a `int`. We, therefore, don't have enough information to answer this question at the present time.*

Comment: now the error is   Msg 8115, Level 16, State 2, Procedure ExtendCode, Line 8
Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int.
The statement has been terminated.

Comment: What is the SQL you're doing when you get that error? I ***assume*** you've changed the SQL to something like `vcItemCode= CONVERT(bigint,'781015020002')` that isn't going to help, `vcItemCode` is still an `int`.

Answer (score 1):

Either The column vcItemCode is an int which can accomodate a max value of 2,147,483,647. The implicit conversion is causing an error when you are trying to update the column with a bigger number than that.

The other reason could be a trigger on the table you are trying to update on .

Third reason i can think of is that CaTbItemRequest is a view which is showing the itemcode as varchar(50) but the underlying column is an int.